# WooCommerce: change cart button text in loop to icon

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I want to change the cart button text on archive pages to an icon.

I found a snippet which does that. But that also changes the link of the cart button:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'ts_replace_add_to_cart_button', 10, 2 );
function ts_replace_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product ) {
    if (is_product_category() || is_shop()) {
        $button_text = __("View Product", "woocommerce");
        $button_link = $product->get_permalink();
        $button = '<a href="' . $button_link . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    return $button;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change only the text of the button?

I know, that I could change the template file `/loop/add-to-cart.php`. But I need a solution based on a function.

Comment: Do you have the outputed element structure ?

Comment: You mean the HTML? `<a href="?add-to-cart=7827" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="7827" data-product_sku="12800007827" aria-label="Name" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick. You can adjust the conditional statement. Right now it's covering any `taxonomy.php` page, which are an archive page for the products (Woocommerce), and the regular `archive.php` page.

```
<?php
/**
* do_action( 'wp_customize_add_to_cart_archive' )
* This hook is fired once WP, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_loaded/
*/
add_action( 'wp_customize_add_to_cart_archive', function() {
  function wp_customize_add_to_cart_archive( $subject ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && is_archive() || is_tax() ) {
      $search = [
        '/>Add to cart</', // ... >< with the brackets, to be sure to target the right Home word
        // ... etc.
      ];
      $replace = [
        '><i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i><', // ... Our replacement for Add to cart using a font awesome icon
        // ... etc.
      ];
      $subject = preg_replace( $search, $replace, $subject );
      return $subject;
    };
  };
  ob_start( 'wp_customize_add_to_cart_archive' );
} ); ?>
```

| Function | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `is_admin` | [Determines whether the current request is for an administrative interface page.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) |
| `is_archive` | [Determines whether the query is for an existing archive page.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/) |
| `is_tax` | [Determines whether the query is for an existing custom taxonomy archive page.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) |

---

### Learn more

- `preg_replace` @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- `ob_start` @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php